# how can I use iteration to make this more efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I am new to python and I know I can make the following code more concise using iteration (such as a for loop), I am just not sure how to

this is what I have so far

```
# Open file for reading
dataFileRead = open(filename, "r")

# Read file content into a list - to be completed - Part 1

SampleData = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(filename)]
print(SampleData)

variables = [mazeWidth, mazeHeight, aNumOfTreasures, aNumOfBombs, emptyCell, treasure, bomb, exitGate, boundary, boundarySide]
mazeWidth = SampleData[0]
mazeHeight = SampleData[1]
aNumOfTreasures = SampleData[2]
aNumOfBombs = SampleData[3]
emptyCell = SampleData[4]
treasure = SampleData[5]
bomb = SampleData[6]
mario = SampleData[7]
exitGate = SampleData[8]
boundary = SampleData[9]
boundarySide = SampleData[10]
```

any input helps! thank you

Comment: What's the use of the `variables` list ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary to hold the variables' names and values instead of having separate variables:

```
variable_names = ['mazeWidth', 'mazeHeight', 'aNumOfTreasures', 'aNumOfBombs', 'emptyCell', 'treasure', 'bomb', 'exitGate', 'boundary', 'boundarySide']

variables = {
  name: SampleData[i] for i, name in enumerate(variable_names)
}
```

Later, if you want the value of the variable `exitGate` for example, you can use:

```
variables['exitGate']
```

And for assignment, use:

```
variables['exitGate'] = "some value"
```

If you want separate variables however, you can use this:

```
for i, name in enumerate(variable_names):
    globals()[name] = SampleData[i]
```

And later you can access (get and set) the variables just as you normally would do (`print(exitGate); exitGate = "some value"`).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need these 11 variables to exist with their own names, abstain from any trick. 11 lines is no big deal.

Otherwise, keep working with the list `SampleData`.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to use your method (which I wouldn't – I'll detail that later), I would edit your code as follows to combine `SampleData` with `variables` using `zip()` and `dict()`.

```py
# Open file for reading
dataFileRead = open(filename, "r")

# Read file content into a list - to be completed - Part 1

SampleData = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(filename)]
print(SampleData)

#previously known as variables
variable_names = ["mazeWidth", "mazeHeight", "aNumOfTreasures", "aNumOfBombs", "emptyCell", "treasure", "bomb", "exitGate", "boundary", "boundarySide"]

variables = dict(zip(variable_names, SampleData))
print(variables)
```

This will combine both lists into one dictionary. This way, if you want to access the number of bombs, or the width of the maze, all you have to do is write:

```py
print(variables["aNumOfBombs"])
```

Dictionaries are useful like that. However, I would redo the system entirely. As your reading from a file anyway, I think you should make use of the json module and store the data that way. All of the code above would instead look like:

```py
import json

with open(filename, "r") as var_file:
    variables = json.load(var_file)
```

The only difference is how you structure the file you read from, which would instead look something like this:

```
{
    "mazeWidth": 5,
    "mazeHeight": 10,
    "aNumOfTreasures": 4,
    "aNumOfBombs": 16,
    "emptyCell": "whatever",
    "treasure": true,
    "bomb": true,
    "exitGate": false,
    "boundary": "red",
    "boundarySide": "NW"
}
```

Look into it!